# How to loop through object for finding a particular value using typescript and react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to hide a button if there is atleast one order or subareas that at least one orders whose status 'ACCEPTED' or 'DONE'.
How can I hide the "Hide me" Menu item when either item has at least one area with order status 'ACCEPTED' OR 'DONE' or at least one area with subareas order with status 'ACCEPTED' or 'DONE'.

Below is the react code with the item I am trying to process

```
function Parent() {
    const item = {
        owner: {
            id: '1',
            cognitoId: '2',
        },
        areas: [{
            id: '1',
            orders: [
                {
                    id: '1',
                    status: 'ASSIGNED',
                }, {
                    id: '2',
                    status: 'ACCEPTED',
                } 
            ],
            subAreas: [
                {
                    id: '1',
                    orders: [
                        {
                            id: '4',
                            status: 'DONE',
                        }
                    ],
                }
            ]
        }, {
            id: '2',
            orders: [{
                    id: '3',
                    status: 'ASSIGNED',
                }, {
                    id: '4',
                    status: 'ACCEPTED',
                }
            ],
            subAreas: [{
                    id: '2',
                    orders: [{
                            id: '5',
                            status: 'DONE',
                        }, {
                            id: '6',
                            status: 'ACCEPTED',
                        }
                    ],
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

return ({
    item && item.owner && item.owner.cognitoId && (
         < Menu > Hide me <  / Menu > )
});
```

}

this Item is reference to how the data will look.
For additional information...Item is of type Item which is like below

```
export interface Item {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    areas?: Area[];
}

export interface Area {
    id: string;
    Orders?: Order[];
    subAreas?: Area[];
}

export interface Order {
    id: string;
    status: OrderStatus; //this is the one we are looping through
}

export interface OrderStatus {
    NEW = 'NEW',
    ASSIGNED = 'ASSIGNED',
    SENT = 'SENT',
    ACCEPTED = 'ACCEPTED',
    REJECTED = 'REJECTED',
    DONE = 'DONE',
}
```

**what i have tried is like below**

```
const hasDoneAccepted = () => {
   return Object
      .keys(item)
          .some(key =>
              (key === 'status' &&
              ['DONE', 'ACCEPTED'].indexOf(item[key]) > -1) ||
              (typeof item[key] === 'object' &&
              hasDoneAccepted(item[key])));
 }
```

But this gives me an error like below,

Element implicitly has any type because expression of type "status" cant be used on index type 'Item'. property status doesnt exist on type 'Item'.

i am new to using typescript and not sure whats going wrong. could someone help me with this. thanks.

**EDIT:**
using the solution provided

```
const hasAcceptedOrDoneOrders = 
    item.areas?.reduce<Order[]>((acc, area) => { //error here
        area.orders?.forEach(order => acc.push(order));
        area.subAreas?.forEach(subArea => subArea.orders?.forEach(order => 
            acc.push(order)));
            return acc;
    }, [])
    .some(order => order.status === "ACCEPTED" || order.status === "DONE");
 }
```

this gives me an here at line

```
item.areas?.reduce<Order[]>((acc, area) =>
```

"parsing error: expression expected"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looping through the object is always an option. I'd use a helper method too. Something like this:

```
hideBool = false;
for(cost area of item.areas()) {
    if(hideBool) { break; }
    hideBool = this.checkArray(area.orders);
    if(!hideBool) { 
            for(const subArea of area.subAreas) {
        hideBool = this.checkArray(subArea);
        if(hideBool) { break; }
            } 
        }
}


checkArray(array: any[]) {
    for( const item in array) {
             if(item.status === 'ACCEPTED' || item.status === 'DONE') {
                   return true;
        }
        }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: where are we using the hideBool value. how can that hideBool value returned and used to hide the hide me button. thanks.

Comment: I'm not the most familiar with react, but this article could help: https://www.telerik.com/blogs/how-to-show-and-hide-elements-in-react
I know there must be a way to conditionally show or hide things based on a boolean, so best of luck to you!

Comment: thanks i solved it . but your answer was easy to read and there is minor mistakes like in checkArray method in is used instead of for in for loop.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can write the filter function:

```js
const hasAcceptedOrDoneOrders = 
    item.areas?.reduce<Order[]>((acc, area) => {
        area.orders?.forEach(order => acc.push(order));
        area.subAreas?.forEach(subArea => subArea.orders?.forEach(order => acc.push(order)));
        return acc;
      }, [])
      .some(order => order.status === "ACCEPTED" || order.status === "DONE");
```

and use it to conditional display React element:

```
return !hasAcceptedOrDoneOrders && <Menu>Hide me</Menu>;
```

However, to eliminate all the TypeScript syntax errors you need to correctly type the `item` object and fix the data schema:

```js
const item: Item = {
    id: "1",
    name: "Item1",
    owner: { id: "1", cognitoId: "2" },
    areas: [
      {
        id: "1",
        orders: [
          { id: "1", status: OrderStatus.ASSIGNED },
          { id: "2", status: OrderStatus.ACCEPTED }
        ],
        subAreas: [
          {
            id: "1",
            orders: [{ id: "4", status: OrderStatus.DONE }]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: "2",
        orders: [
          { id: "3", status: OrderStatus.ASSIGNED },
          { id: "4", status: OrderStatus.ACCEPTED }
        ],
        subAreas: undefined
      }
    ]
  };
```

Schema:

```js
interface Item {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  areas?: Area[];
  owner: any;
}

enum OrderStatus {
  NEW = 'NEW',
  ASSIGNED = 'ASSIGNED',
  SENT = 'SENT',
  ACCEPTED = 'ACCEPTED',
  REJECTED = 'REJECTED',
  DONE = 'DONE',
}
```

Comment: what is the ?. doing like in here item.areas?.reduce<Order[]>((acc, area) =>  also could you explain your answer as what it does the filter part. would be helpful. thanks.

Comment: also updated my question about the error i am encountering using the solution provided.